# Angular and angular-translate : Get proposedLanguage in config

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-translate

I'm building an angular app. A sort of template to start future projects faster. It's an open source project so you can find the whole project here : https://github.com/maxime1992/webTemplate

I'm using ui-router and angular-translate. I wanted users to be able to share url with current language in it. As you can see [here](https://github.com/maxime1992/webTemplate/blob/master/site_dev/assets/app_components/app/app.js), in the default redirection of ui-router i'm using a default language variable which as to be set first :

```
// define default language code
var default_lang = 'fr';

// default redirection
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/'+default_lang+'/home');
```

So far, so good.
Now i would like to detect user's language. I found out [this](http://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/07_multi-language#multi-language_determining-preferred-language-automatically) in angular-translate doc.

But in my angular config, if i ask the library to set language automatically and get the new language, it returns undefined.

```
$translateProvider.determinePreferredLanguage();
console.log($translateProvider.use()); // return undefined
```

I can detect it in my controller with :

```
console.log($translate.proposedLanguage()); // return 'en'
```

BUT it is too late. I need to detect it in config. Otherwhise, i don't know where to redirect user if lang argument is not in url ...

Do you have any idea ? I really need to find a solution as fast as possible for my work. If i wasn't clear, just tell me and i'll add/edit my question.

Thanks !

Comment: I'm really stuck here, some help would be awesome ! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usage is as follows.

1. During config phase

   ```
   // call to try to find out browser locale
   $translateProvider.determinePreferredLanguage();
   ```
2. After config phase

   ```
   // If determinePreferredLanguage was successful preferredLanguage
   // will return the browser locale. Eg 'en_EN'
   // Otherwise it will return empty string.
   var preferredLanguage = $translate.preferredLanguage(); // returns browser locale
   ```

After that, you can just navigate to the url you want, Eg:

```
$state.go('home', {lang: preferredLanguage});
```